# genymotion drag and drong a file or picture put it in sdcard/download

Tags: android, genymotion

I am a new user of the genymotion when i drag and drop a picture in the device it said "your file is saved in sdcard/download" and i can't find it , i tried to add a shared folder in the virtual box but nothing work please tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

A shared folder allows you to create a common folder between your Genymotion devices and your host (your computer). You don't need to create a shared folder for your use case.

After dropping your picture, you can access with the "File Explorer" application. 
You will find your picture on the sdcard/download folder.